# How to see what functions can be optimized using V8 and d8

Tags: javascript, v8

In [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) in "V8 Optimization Tips" section written what "For more information on what functions can and can’t be optimized, you can use --trace-opt file.js with the d8 shell utility that comes with V8". I installed v8 and d8 and then do `d8 --trace-opt-verbose app.js` where app.js content is:

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x+y;
}

add(1, 2);
add('a','b');

function foo() {
    var a = [1, 2, 3]
    var b = [4, 5, 6];
    var c = a.concat(b);
}

function bar() {
    var a = [1, 2, 3]
    var b = [4, 5, 6];
    var c = a.concat(b);
    return c;
}

var d = bar();
```

And I've got:

```
[disabled optimization for 0xea95f253e59 <SharedFunctionInfo InstantiateFunction>, reason: TryCatchStatement]
[disabled optimization for 0xea95f25f391 <SharedFunctionInfo ConfigureTemplateInstance>, reason: TryFinallyStatement]
[disabled optimization for 0xea95f24c041 <SharedFunctionInfo DefaultNumber>, reason: Call to a JavaScript runtime function]
```

What happened? How I can use d8 right?

Comment: You might also want to look at Petka Antonov's guide to V8 optimization: [Optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @bob in this code nothing is hot so nothing is optimized. you either need to have a loop (or you can force optimization with `%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall`)

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov and I can use Node.js, because Node.js uses the V8? Is it same?

Comment: yes, you can use node.js. it's just an outdated V8 - but it's still V8.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy thanks! Good article.